# How to set the starting point of the video file a little bit later

Tags: android, html, ios, video, ffmpeg

I would like to set the starting point of the video file a little bit later like 0.01 seconds 
when I open the detail page of the video file at smartphon site by using the ffmpeg, and the coding I tried is below.

```
for i in /xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/*.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -ss 0.01 "/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/$(basename "$i" .mp4).mp4"; done
```

The reason for that is because when I open the detail page of the video file at smartphone site(iOS and android)
it is set to stop to play the video by default(I can not set to start the video automatically) with the circled start button at the white background.(The pc site starts the video automatically by default.)
 So I would like to see the actual picture from the video file by delaying the starting point at the smartphone detail page.

My understanding is that the starting point of 0 second is the white screen, and then the picture starts to be displayed continuosly after that.

With the command above it does not set it later even though I don't get any error.

Can anyone please help me out to code the right command for this case? Or is there any other way for this case?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. How can I "open the detail page of a video file at smartphone site" so I can see what you are trying to describe? Do you just want to set the poster image? Can you not just use the `poster` option in the `<video>` element (assuming you're using HTML5 video)?

Comment: LordNeckbeard, Thank you. you solved the problem I've facing for such a long time by reading the question which is difficult to understand.
I just did not know how to use the poster in video tag, and in this case I set it like poster="the video image" which I coded to create from the video file by using ffmpeg with your support before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `poster` attribute in the HTML5 `<video>` element to choose an image to represent the video before playback begins.

```
<video src="video.webm" poster="image.jpg">
```